# Django-admin executing, but no project is created in the virual directory

Tags: python, django

I have django and anaconda installed on a company system running comodo AV. upon running the command "django-admin startproject appone" it runs and no folders or app is created in the virtual environment.

Comment: What do you mean "in the virtual environment" ? This command create a project in the current working directory...

Comment: I am sorry for my late response, I got to realize comodo AV was creating a virtual drive and storing my files in there.